# JavaFX auto scaling

Tags: java, javafx, scaling, scenebuilder

I want, when I increase the window, that the elements also get bigger.

See here: [image: See here]

I'm using JavaFX Scenebuilder 2.0: [image]

**Start.fxml** :

```
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<AnchorPane cacheHint="SCALE" focusTraversable="true" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="delteRowBtn" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#delRowAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="51.0" text="Zeile" />
      <Button fx:id="addColumnBtn" layoutX="193.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addColumnAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="51.0" text="Spalte" />
      <Button fx:id="moveBtn" layoutX="258.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="MOVE" />
      <Button fx:id="linkBtn" layoutX="363.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="LINK" />
      <Button fx:id="splitBtn" layoutX="468.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="SPLIT" />
      <Button fx:id="tcodeBtn" layoutX="574.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="TRANSCODE" />
      <Button fx:id="cnvrtBtn" layoutX="679.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="CONVERT" />
      <Button fx:id="saveBtn" layoutX="684.0" layoutY="551.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="SAVE" />
      <TableView fx:id="sourceTable" editable="true" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="40.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="190.0" prefWidth="766.0" />
      <TableView fx:id="finalTable" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="348.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="190.0" prefWidth="766.0" />
      <Button fx:id="openBtn" layoutX="572.0" layoutY="551.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="OPEN" />
      <TextField fx:id="srcInput" editable="false" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="551.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="495.0" />
      <TextField editable="false" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="11.0" text="Source File" />
      <TextField editable="false" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="319.0" text="Converted File" />
      <Button fx:id="delteColumnBtn" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#delColumnAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="51.0" text="Spalte" />
      <Button fx:id="addRowBtn" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="272.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addRowAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="51.0" text="Zeile" />
      <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="248.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="104.0" text="    HINZUFÜGEN" textAlignment="CENTER" />
      <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="248.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="104.0" text="      LÖSCHEN" textAlignment="CENTER" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you include a Start.fxml file?

Comment: What items do you want to scale with the window re-size? Just the TableView's or do you want the Button and TextFields to scale as well?

Comment: All elements(tableviews,buttons,textfields,..) should scale ..

Comment: You can use a GridPane and set the [setHgrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) and [setVgrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setVgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) of all the elements as `Priority.Always`. You can also use a combination of other layouts, but this one is the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

you need to anchor to all four sides. This will cause them to stretch when the screen is enlarged. If you only want to widen but not get taller, anchor to left, right, and top, but not bottom. It may be easier for you to test your interface using the graphical scene builder to set small details like that without having to do trial and error compiling. You will still be able to edit the fxml and css files manually if you do this. Here is the link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html

I find it very helpful to use in conjunction with handcoding while working with JavaFX